# jQueryUI toggle scale effect on button

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got a button inside of a Bootstrap4 navbar.  I want to have it scale (grow and shrink, sort of like it's popping out of the page) a few times to draw attention to it inside of `$(document).ready(function(){`.

I have the jQueryUI cdn in my html and I'm sure the library is loading properly, but I'm getting a strange effect.  It may be because of some conflicting settings within my navbar, but the effect is also just not performing how I think it should be.  I've included the **jfiddle** [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tx09cwza/8/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
      for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
        $( "#toggle" ).toggle({effect: "scale", percent: 2.0});
     $( "#toggle" ).toggle({effect: "scale", percent: 1.0});
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-dark" style="background-color: lightslategray;">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Airforce Inventory Information Database</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" id="toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="icon-bar top-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar middle-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        </button>
</nav>
```

Comment: Note: code snippet does not contain bootstrap4 cdn, thus it is not an entirely accurate reproduction of my situation.  For a 1 to 1, please inspect the included jsfiddle

Comment: And how exactly you want it to perform...    As in fiddle it does toggle 5 times

Comment: I'm wanting it to grow and shrink from the center of the button (right now it seems to travel down and to the right).  I think it should be a simple matter of changing the `origin` argument in `toggle(...)` but I can't seem to get the behavior how I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend adding a CSS class to achieve this animation. Here is an example of adding a class with jQuery, then looping the animation 5 times with CSS:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
      $( "#toggle" ).addClass('attention');
});
```

```css
.attention {
  animation: zoom-in-out 0.5s ease-in-out 5;
}

@keyframes zoom-in-out {
  0% { transform: scale(1); }
  50% { transform: scale(0.5); }
  100% { transform: scale(1); } 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-dark" style="background-color: lightslategray;">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Airforce Inventory Information Database</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" id="toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="icon-bar top-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar middle-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        </button>
</nav>
```

Comment: Wow, wasn't aware that sort of functionality was available in CSS.  This is exactly what I needed, thanks!  Upvoted!